# Rewriting code in python with use of kivy gone wrong

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to rewrite some code. My main problem is that I don't understand the `build(self)` function in `Test(App)`. Does `self.swiper_manager` reference `swiper_manager = None` and `start_screen.ids.swiper_manager` reference `MDSwiperManager: id: swiper_manager` in the .kv file?
Code that I am trying to rewrite.

```
class MySwiperManager(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Test(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
    swiper_manager = None

    def build(self):
        start_screen = MySwiperManager()
        self.swiper_manager = start_screen.ids.swiper_manager
        paginator = MDSwiperPagination()
        paginator.screens = self.swiper_manager.screen_names
        paginator.manager = self.swiper_manager
        self.swiper_manager.paginator = paginator
        start_screen.add_widget(paginator)

        return start_screen
```

The code below is my best attempt to rewrite
Name of file: Prelogin/prescreenmanager.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.managerswiper import MDSwiperPagination
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class MySwiperManager(BoxLayout):
    pass

class PreScreenManager(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
    swiper_manager = None
    start_screen = MySwiperManager()
    swiper_manager = start_screen.ids.swiper_manager
    paginator = MDSwiperPagination()
    paginator.screens = swiper_manager.screen_names
    paginator.manager = swiper_manager
    swiper_manager.paginator = paginator
    start_screen.add_widget(paginator)
```

The context of my code is as follows:
Name of file: Prelogin/prescreenmanager.kv

```
<ScreenOne@Screen>:
    name: 'screen one'
    Label: 
        text: 'Hello World'

<ScreenTwo@Screen>:
    name: 'screen two'


<ScreenThree@Screen>:
    name: 'screen three'


<ScreenFour@Screen>:
    name: 'screen four'



<ScreenFive@Screen>:
    name: 'screen five'


<PreScreenManager>:
    MySwiperManager:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDSwiperManager:
            id: swiper_manager

            ScreenOne: 

            ScreenTwo:

            ScreenThree:

            ScreenFour:

            ScreenFive:
```

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

# Load the kv files
Builder.load_file("Prelogin/prescreenmanger.kv")

from Prelogin.prescreenmanger import PreScreenManager


class MainApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
AnchorLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: "Start/Background.png"   
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'
    Image:
        source: 'Start/Loginlogo.png'
        keep_ratio: False
        allow_stretch: True
        opacity: 1
        size_hint: 1, 0.25
        pos_hint: (0,0)  
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        PreScreenManager:
            id: PreScreenManager
```

Error (That I don't understand)

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Bruger\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-11-23_9.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] v0.102.0
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 24.20.100.6286'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 24.20.100.6286'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'swiper_manager'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Bruger\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Python - Java - kivy\Kivy2\Initium\Start\main.py", line 10, in <module>
     from Prelogin.prescreenmanger import PreScreenManager
   File "C:\Users\Bruger\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Python - Java - kivy\Kivy2\Initium\Prelogin\prescreenmanger.py", line 16, in <module>
     class PreScreenManager(Screen):
   File "C:\Users\Bruger\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Python - Java - kivy\Kivy2\Initium\Prelogin\prescreenmanger.py", line 21, in PreScreenManager
     swiper_manager = start_screen.ids.swiper_manager
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: In your `main.py`, what happens if you replace `MainApp().run()` with `Test().run()`.

Comment: The code in Test works as intended. The problem is that if I do Test().run() instead of MainApp().run() the rest of my code isn't runned. The main problem is to do MainApp().run() and get the code in Test to excute as if I did the Test().run() some where in the documents If i have to excute it in my main.py or the file with the Test class I don't know.

Comment: Extremely difficult to understand what you are trying to do. I see three references to 'kv' strings/files. but one is not shown (`Prelogin/prescreenmanger.kv`). Your comment says the if you make my suggested change, then the rest of your code doesn't run. What code doesn't run?

Comment: I left ```Prelogin/prescreenmanger.kv``` out because it contains the same code as activity and I thought It was not nesserary to show since I don't think my problem lies there. The code I am trying to get to run is the code in ```class Test(App):```. There are many documents in my project and ```MainApp().run()``` is the function that runs all them. I am now trying to get the code inside  ```class Test(App):``` to run so it alters the ```class MySwiperManager(BoxLayout)```. If I do ```Test().run()``` the code inside ```class Test(App):``` is runned but it is also the only code that is runned.

Comment: I still an unable to understand what you are trying to do, but here are some hints. Never do something like `ClassName = ClassName()` (you do this twice in your `MainApp`). Perhaps what you want to do is to extend the `Test` `App`? If you define `MainApp` as `class MainApp(TestApp):`, then `MainApp` will inherit all the `TestApp` methods, including `build()`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to think what my problem is more clearly or reformulate myself.

Comment: Okay, I have now rewritten my Qustion to hopefully make more sense of what I am trying to do and failing at.

Answer (score 1):

The `build()` method of an `App` returns the `Widget` that will be the root of the `App` display, The lines in the class `TestApp` before the `def build()`

```
theme_cls = ThemeManager()
theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
swiper_manager = None
```

create class variables that are shared by all instances of the `Test` class (but since it is an `App`, there should only be one instance).

So, in the `build()` method, `self.swiper_manager` references the class variable named `swiper_manager`.  And the line with `ids` references the `id` in the `kv` file.

That is all fine, but in your `prescreenmanager.py`, you have a bunch of code that is not in any method. That code, like the class variable creation in `Test`, is run when Python loads the class, even before the `App` is built. So, at that point, the `ids` have not yet been defined, so you get the error you see.

And I still don't know what you are trying to do with that dangling code in `prescreenmanager.py`.